# CSS background-color on table td displaying incorrectly in Internet Explorer 6

Tags: html, css, html-table, background-color, internet-explorer-6

I have some pretty simple HTML and CSS that doesn't work in Internet Explorer 6.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>        
            table td.one.read {background-color:#FFD700;}
            table td.two.read {background-color:#0000ff;}
            table td.three.read {background-color:#ff8c00;}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table>
            <tr class="head">
                <td></td>
                <td class='one read'>one</td>
                <td class='two read'>two</td>
                <td class='three read'>three</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Legend</td>
                <td class='one read'>1</td>
                <td class='two read'>2</td>
                <td class='three read'>3</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

A simple table that has different background colors for each column. I've removed a bunch of other CSS/HTML to keep things simple. The problem is all the columns show up as the same orange color in Internet Explorer 6, works fine in [Firefox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Firefox).

How can I make it work?

Comment: Please stop supporting IE6! http://www.bringdownie6.com/

Comment: @Doug sometimes you don't have a choice. If I could ignore IE6 I would, but I can't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in IE6.

If you have a CSS selector with multiple class names (eg, `.three.read`), IE6 will ignore all of the class names except the last one.

Therefore, IE6 sees three CSS rules for the selector `table td.read`.

To solve this, you can combine your classes.  (eg, `<td class='OneRead'>` and `table td.OneRead {background-color:#FFD700;}`)

Answer (score 1):

Multiple classes are not supported in IE6, have to wait a few more years before IE6 dies. For now though, you can create separate classes for colors.